# Canvas en blanco al pintar con FileReader Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, filereader

Estoy intentando extraer una imagen con **FileReader**, si es mayor a aspecto 16:9 reducirle el tamaño a 1920 x 1080. Cree una variable llamada *bgimage* que contiene el base 64 sin embargo al pasarla al *canvas* sale transparente.

Soy relativamente nuevo en esto de *canvas* y *filereader* y no he encontrado solución por ningún lado.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("inputCustomBg").files[0]);
    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        var bgimage = new Image();
        bgimage.src = oFREvent.target.result;
        var tempW = bgimage.width;
        var tempH = bgimage.height;
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 1920;
        canvas.height = 1080;
        if (tempW > 1920) {
            tempW = 1920;
        } else {
            tempW = bgimage.width;
        }
        if (tempH > 1080) {
            tempH = 1080;
        } else {
            tempH = bgimage.height;
        }
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(bgimage, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
        var img2 = new Image();
        img2.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        $("#customBgDiv").append("<img src='" + img2.src + "'>");
    };
}
```

De antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve revisando tu código, y lo que pude notar que no espera a que la imagen este cargada, por lo que al llegar a las medidas no tiene toda la información de la imagen, lo que le agregue es el evento onload de la imagen, para asegurar que este cargada antes de continuar con las medidas,

```js
function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("inputCustomBg").files[0]);
    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        $("#customBgDiv").empty();
        var bgimage = new Image();
        bgimage.src = oFREvent.target.result;
        bgimage.onload = () => {
            var tempW = bgimage.width;
            var tempH = bgimage.height;
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = 1920;
            canvas.height = 1080;
            if (tempW > 1920) {
                tempW = 1920;
            } else {
                tempW = bgimage.width;
            }
            if (tempH > 1080) {
                tempH = 1080;
            } else {
                tempH = bgimage.height;
            }
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(bgimage, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);

            var img2 = new Image();
            img2.src = canvas.toDataURL();
            $("#customBgDiv").append(img2);
        };
    };
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="inputCustomBg" onchange="PreviewImage()">
    <div id="customBgDiv" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid red;;">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!